# Determining LED power supply

Tags: led, calculation

I have the following LED array:

[LED Circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDRfX.jpg)

I need help calculating the power supply needed. Rather than sticking it on an adjustable power supply, setting the current limit to 700mA and turning up the voltage I would prefer to learn how to calculate the optimal voltage. The LEDS and 1W and limited to 700mA and instead of just 5 columns my actual circuit has 14 columns. Please can someone teach me how to do the calculations for this circuit. If it were a straight forward parallel string of LEDs, I would not bother you, but the additional junctions throw me off a bit.

Please don't suggest alternative layouts as this is what I am reverse engineering.

Thanks,

Dylan

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Comment: Sorry, I will remove it and take it to the appropriate forum. Once again, sorry about this.